tabularray, increasing space below header
I have a table like this
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\euro}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[long]{
        colspec={
                Q[l]
                Q[r]@{\hskip 2pt}
                Q[l]
                X[l]
                Q[r]
                Q[r]
        },
        rowhead = 1,
        rows = { rowsep=1pt }
}
        Date & \SetCell[c=2]{l}{{{Qty}}} & & Description & Unit price & Net price \\ \hline
        01.01. & 1 & pce & item & 99,90 € & 99,90 € \\
        [...lots of instances snipped....]
        01.01. & 1 & pce & item & 99,90 € & 99,90 € \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}

It would be nice to have some additional space below the (repeated) \hline, but the obvious row{1}={ belowsep=3pt } increased the space above the \hline.
On the other hand row{2} = { abovesep=3pt } increases the space exactly as I'd like it, but (of course) only to the first page.
Is there any solution to this?

There's no solution to this at the moment. There's a pull request with a patch though: https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/pull/493

Add \hborder{belowspace=3pt} after \hline.
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\euro}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}[long]{
    colspec={
      Q[l]
      Q[r]@{\hskip 2pt}
      Q[l]
      X[l]
      Q[r]
      Q[r]
    },
    rowhead = 1,
    rows = { rowsep=1pt }
  }
  Date & \SetCell[c=2]{l}{{{Qty}}} & & Description & Unit price & Net price \\
  \hline \hborder{belowspace=3pt}
  01.01. & 1 & pce & item & 99,90 € & 99,90 € \\
  ...
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


This seemed to be fine at a first glance, but if I use different content for each row it reveals that the 1st (real) row is duplicated on every page because auf rowhead = 2. This should not be the case.

@ShowFox You are right. The correct value is rowhead=1. And seems to me this is a bug of tabularray: \hline and \hborder should work the same.
